# In MVC Music Store Tutorial, @url.content

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Between these two lines of code the second one works but the code provided in the _layout.cshtml file, in line one is, as is, right from the MVC 3 project template.
I have followed the instructions quite meticulously and line two below works.
Is there some additional reference file that must be loaded or a setting in Webconfig necessary in order to use the html helpers?

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between both statements:

```
@Url.Content();
```

will put its root reference at your website's base URL. Hence in your case, the CSS should be located under "http://localhost:port/Content". If this is not the case, you need to update the path with any additional subfolders. Example:

```
@Url.Content("~/Static/Content/Site.css");
```

The second line will reference the Content folder at the same level as that of the folder containing your HTML file. For example, this would work:

```
/Static/Content/Site.css
/Static/Views/Index.html
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...but, I have no additional subfolders.  both lines of code, as I understand them, reference the same location. Am I wrong.

Comment: @AllenB They may reference to the same place, but the first one searches for an absolute path that contains `/Content/site.css`, so it is possible to move that folder with the site.css file in, to anywhere, and still have it working. In the second line, you say the file is located one directory up, and then into the `/content/site.css` folder from there. Makes any sense?

Comment: Ok... this does make sense, but doesn't change the problem that I am having.  Site.css is in the Content folder. The content folder is at the same level as the Controllers, Views, and Models folders.  What am I missing?

Comment: Additionally,... after trying some other combinations with this code. This also works, but I think that this is no longer a relative path.         <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />